# I want to fill a new column col c: if col a entries are blank then col c is blank otherwise entries from col b

Tags: r

My present data:

```
col a    col b    
 A         G
 G         A
           C
 T         G  
           A
 C         
 A         T
 G         C

 A
```

If col a is blank then blank in the new column c, otherwise entries from col b.

New data required:

```
col a    col b  Mutant_SNP_2  
 A         G         G
 G         A         A
           C
 T         G         G
           A
 C         
 A         T         T
 G         C         C

 A
```

Comment: What is what here? Please format your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
df$Mutant_SNP_2 <- ifelse(df$colb == '', '', df$colc)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is sort of working, but I now have numbers in the new column-1s for blanks and other numbers for the letters??

Comment: @Cathyt10 when you read your data, add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your command. Like this: `read.table("yourfilename.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ , c := ifelse(a=="", "", b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid `ifelse` with two assignments

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Mutant_SNP_2 := ""][cola!="", Mutant_SNP_2 := colb][]
 #    cola colb Mutant_SNP_2
 #1:    A    G            G
 #2:    G    A            A
 #3:         C             
 #4:    T    G            G
 #5:         A             
 #6:    C                  
 #7:    A    T            T
 #8:    G    C            C
 #9:                       
 #10:    A
```